# Storing JSON response in a mobile app

Tags: jquery, json, mobile, local-storage

I want to keep the amount of http requests of my mobile app as lowest as possible so 
I only do one request and store a json locally in a global variable.
After this, I have 3 ways to display the retrived data, so I query the global variable using [jLinq](http://hugoware.net/Projects/jLinq).
This run smoothly on desktop, but it takes more on a smartphone, so I had to reduce it's usage, and to store the result of the query in another global variable.
At the end, I have 3 global variable with the 3 ways I can show my JSON.
I don't like this solution since I'm afraid it can be heavy especially on low memory devices, so I was thinking to store the results with HTML5 web storage: do you think session/local storage would be a better/faster solution or do you think global variable is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactlyt are you trying to store? Hard to tell which method's preferably without digging deeper into what you're actually trying to do. In short, storing data in localStorage is one way to locally store information onto the user's browser.

However, if storing in global variables is doing the job, is see no good reason not to do so. If you wan't to use localStorage and don't need that data to remain after the user has closed down the browser, sessionStorage may be the better alternative.